# Read characters in a string only if I have found the part that I need? [Python]

Tags: python

I phrased the title as well as  I possibly could. Basically, here's my scenario:

I have a **string**, not a file, that I need to read from. In this string, I want to check if there is a certain piece of text in this file. If this text is found in the string, I want to read this text up until I want to stop. More specifically, I'm getting text from a webpage and storing it in a string. In this text, there is an ID that the user is given. I want to check for the text where the ID is given. If I find this text in the string, I want to continue reading until I get the actual ID, then I need to stop reading. Yes, I could just manually read the ID myself, and to be honest it's probably a better solution, but I wanna have some fun and see how something like this could be done, if it can be done at all. Here's the code I have:

```
        if 'Your ID is: ' in str(response):
            print 'Found ID!'

            # I'd probably have something here to store the ID in a variable for later use.
            # I need to be able to check for the ID after I check for the text 'Your ID is: '. I check for this because I know where to start reading from. I have no way of telling what line the ID could possibly be on.
```

Hopefully that made sense. I just need to check if a certain piece of text is in a string, and if it is read just a little more of that text and then store that in a variable for later use. This is probably a rare case and I'll probably never use it, but it never hurts to see what's possible and how it's possible, right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is basic regex/pattern-matching. You can do this easily in Python with ``re`` or basic string manipulation. Please show us you've actually attempted something. This smells of homework/assignment :?

Comment: Homework or assignment...? I don't go to a programming school. I'm asking here because I have no idea _how_ to attempt something like this.

Edit: What's regex/pattern-matching?

Comment: The problem is you *must* show some effort.

Comment: But I had no idea how to do it. The farthest I got was 'if 'Your ID is: ' in str(response): print 'Found ID!''. And that took a few hours to come up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just need to check if a certain piece of text is in a string, and if it is read just a little more of that text and then store that in a variable for later use.

The obvious thing to do is use [`str.partition`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> response = 'Hello there. Your ID is: 6. Your name is: Number 6.'
>>> before, matched, after = response.partition('Your ID is: ')
>>> if after:
...     print after
6. Your name is: Number 6.
```

Or, if it's not found:

```
>>> response = 'Hello there. You have no ID. Your name is: Mud.'
>>> before, matched, after = response.partition('Your ID is: ')
>>> if after:
...     print after
```

---

So how do you get "just a little more"? Well, you have to decide what "a little more" means, but it's very easy to slice or `split` or `partition` the `after` variable to get the appropriate "little". Maybe you want everything up to the first `'.'`? Then:

```
>>> response = 'Hello there. Your ID is: 6. Your name is: Number 6.'
>>> before, matched, after = response.partition('Your ID is: ')
>>> if after:
...     yourid, _, _ = after.partition('.')
...     print yourid
6
```

Comment: str.partition? I'd never heard of it until now, and I spent a good 30 minutes looking through the Python string documentation. Thank you for the help! :-) I'll defiantly look into str.partition some more!

Comment: @Eamonn: Also look at `split`. In this particular case, `partition` is more useful, but `split` comes up more often, and it's important to understand the differences between the two.